# Multiple Custom Variables on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to test 6 custom variables on Google Analytics.

when I go to advanced segments, I can only see visits from the last variable. 
How can I make the rest custom variables work?

I didn't know if I had to put the _trackPageview more than one, so i try putting it after my fifth channel and it still didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var _gaq = _gaq || [];

_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "Channel", "One", 3]); 
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "Channel", "Three", 1]); 
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "Channel", "Four", 1]); 
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "Channel", "Five", 2]); 
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);  
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "Channel", "Six", 2]);
 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);  

  (function() {

    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;

    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

  })();

</script>
```

Can someone help me with this?

How can I get more than one custom variables to work?

Thank you SO!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a limit of 5 custom variables per request.

Duplicate key names cannot be used across slots. `Channel` vars are all in slot 1.

The custom variable with the key name of "Channel" is overwritten by the last custom variable. To illustrate, consider this:

```
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "Visitor-Type", "Member", 1]);
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "Visitor-Type", "Non-Member", 1]);
```

The custom variable of `Visitor-Type` will be recorded as `Non-member` as it overrides the previous custom variable. It will not record a value for both in analytics.

You could try this instead:

```
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "Channel", "One", 3]); 
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 2, "Channel", "Two", 1]); 
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 3, "Channel", "Three", 1]); 
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 4, "Channel", "Four", 1]); 
_gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 5, "Channel", "Five", 2]);
```

See [Custom Variable Usage Guidelines](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html#usage).

Or, use [Event Tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html) instead of some or all of these custom vars.